# $X_n=\frac{n}{\log n}1_{(0,1/n)}$, then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ and $E(X_n) \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that given $X_n=\frac{n}{\log n}1_{(0,1/n)}$, then $X_n \rightarrow 0$ and $E(X_n) \rightarrow 0$.
But as the first part goes to infinity, $\frac{n}{\log n}$ , and the indicator funtion goes  to 0, how can I show that the indicator function converges to 0 faster?
Thanks

Comment: To talk about expectations, you need some underlying probability distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in \mathbb R$. If $x\notin (0, 1)$, $X_n(x)=0$ for all $n$. If $x\in (0,1)$, there is some $N$ such that $n\geq N \implies X_n(x)=0$, hence $X_n(x) \to 0$.

This proves that $X_n\to 0$ pointwise.

Now $E(X_n)=\int \frac{n}{\log n}1_{(0,1/n)}(x) dx =\frac{n}{\log n}\frac 1n=\frac{1}{\log(n)}\to 0 .$

Comment: What is your probability distribution from which you are computing $E[X]$? What is your sample space?

Comment: @Michael $([0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]), \lambda)$.

Comment: These assumptions were not given in the question.  Why should the sample space be $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Michael This is what makes most sense here. And most counter-examples regarding convergence of random variables take place in this setting.

Comment: The assumptions said by Gabriel are correct,  I ommited them on my question. Thanks for the help! I got it now

Comment: @ArthurT if you're satisfied with my answer, don't forget to accept it by pressing the check mark next to it.